# how to get CSS to load when I use my DNS with NGINX

Tags: css, nginx, dns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprLu.png)When i use my IP address (http://167.71.113.70) for my site the site loads with the correct CSS however when i use my domain (rafaelzasas.com) the site still loads but the CSS cant be found.

ive tried changing the server name in the NGINX sites available file.

**Sites available code:**

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name rafaelzasas.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name rafaelzasas.com;
#
#   root /var/www/html;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

**index.html code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WebAppDev-Raff</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./materialize.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <script>

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

      <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Home</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/"> Assignment 1 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="/"> Assignment 1 </a></li>
</ul>

    <table class= "responsive-table centered highlight">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Assignment Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="./Assignment1.html"> Assignment 1 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 2 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 3 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 4 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 5 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 6 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 7 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 8 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 9 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 10 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 11 </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/"> Assignment 12 </a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

The Website still loads when i use my domain but the materialize.css file cant be found.

When i use the inspection tools the only error i get is :
materialize.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**edit** I used the digital ocean tutorial to set up a new server with nginx and it told me to place a new file in the sites available folder: /etc/nginx/sites-available/rafaelzasas.com

that file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/rafaelzasas.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name rafaelzasas.com www.rafaelzasas.com;

        location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ { }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }
}
```

my **config** file looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: This is probably because the path to the file is wrong. sometimes paths can work over localhost and then not work when using a domain. usually you can see in your console (where your 404 error shows) which path is used to embed the css sheet. I'd suggest trying something like ~/materialize.css instead of ./ and if that does not work try it without the "./"

Comment: Yep. Change the path to /styleFile.css

Comment: @TimGerhard But it works when i use my IP address instead of my domain so i know the file [ath is right

Comment: @RafaelZasas have you tried my path options?

Comment: @TimGerhard I did use your file path suggestions to no avail...I managed to break the CSS when I use the IP address now too Saw a tutorial on YouTube that led me to allow all with the uwf command and now none of the links show the page with styling.

Comment: Can you host your website somewhere so i can take a look?

Comment: @TimGerhard its already being hosted with digital ocean at [RafaelZasas.com](http://rafaelzasas.com) . Thanks! I'm also struggling to get an image to load in "Assignment 1"

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? I am unable to load any file (html, css or images) that's why I'm wondering. You can share a screenshot if you'd like to, that should be enough